# Submit form data with Spring Boot using JavaScript submit()

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

[image: interface]

My end goal is to send POST data back to Spring that it can process.  However, I'm not using `<input>` tags.  I want to display a list of items on the screen similar to a list layout in a native mobile interface and submit the POST data with information about the selected item.

The relevant snippet of the HTML is here:

```
<ons-list>
    <form id="form" action="#" th:action="@{/week-hours-summary}" method="post">
        <ons-list-item
                tappable
                th:each="item, iterStat : ${list}"
                th:data-user="${item.value.getTitle()}"
                th:data-date="${date}"
                onclick="submit(document.getElementById('form'), this.getAttribute('data-user'), this.getAttribute('data-date'), 'week-hours-summary')">
            <div class="center">
                <span class="list-item__title" th:text="${item.value.getTitle().toUpperCase()}">Not Sure</span>
                <span class="list-item__subtitle" th:text="${item.value.getSubtitle().toUpperCase()}">RT:38 | OT:3.25</span>
            </div>
        </ons-list-item>
    </form>
</ons-list>
```

Here is the JavaScript that actually performs the submission, since it seems to me that I cannot pass the form data any other way (is there a better way!?):

```
function submit(form, username, date, page) {
    console.log("username: [" + username + "]");
    console.log("date: [" + date + "]");
    console.log("page: [" + page + "]");
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");

    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = page;

    element1.value=username;
    element1.textContent=username;
    element1.setAttribute("field", username);
    element1.setAttribute("th:field", username);
    element1.setAttribute("th:value", username);
    element1.name="user";
    element1.id="user";
    form.appendChild(element1);

    element2.value=date;
    element2.textContent=date;
    element2.setAttribute("field", date);
    element2.setAttribute("th:field", date);
    element2.setAttribute("th:value", date);
    element2.name="date";
    element2.id="date";
    form.appendChild(element2);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```

And here is the method signature on the receiving end in the `@Controller`:

```
@PostMapping("/week-hours-summary")
public String showUserWeekHoursByDay(@ModelAttribute String user, @ModelAttribute String dateString, Model model)
```

The variables are passed into the method, but both the user and date fields are `null`.  Why is that?  What is so magical about form data from an `<input>` tag that Spring can process it, but it won't process a form populated with JavaScript?

The web console shows that JavaScript is indeed grabbing the values and sending them as part of the form.  Why are they `null` in Spring?

Comment: look into FormData() and using it with ajax or better, fetch().

Comment: Is there a reason to use `submit()` only or do you allowed other ways as `ajax`?